# Multiple IQueryable in one controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller for my entire database, the code is below:

```
public class YogaController : DbDataController<Yoga.Models.YOGAEntities>
{
    public YogaController()
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<Yoga.Models.Action> GetActions(int BugId)
//GetActions retrieves "actions" table from the db, not Actions in MVC term 
    {
        return DbContext.Actions.Where(x => x.FK_BugsID == BugId);
    }
    public IQueryable<Yoga.Models.Label> GetRequiredLabels()
    {
        return DbContext.Labels.Where(x => x.IsRequired == true);
    }
    public IQueryable<Yoga.Models.Role> GetRoles()
    {
        return DbContext.Roles;
    }
    public IQueryable<Role> GetRoles2() //TODO: finish this
    {
        return DbContext.Roles.Where(x => x.RoleID == 1);
    }
    public IQueryable<Tag> GetTags(int actionid)
    {
        return DbContext.Tags.Where(x => x.J_Tags.Any(y => y.FK_ActionID == actionid));
    }
}
```

As you can see I have multiple IQueryable in one controller, each querying a different table. Is it something that's forbidden? Because when I go to `localhost/api/Yoga/GetActions` or `localhost/api/Yoga/GetRequiredLabels` I get the error message:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
 System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Yoga.Models.Label] GetRequiredLabels() on type Yoga.Controllers.YogaController
 System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Yoga.Models.Role] GetRoles() on type Yoga.Controllers.YogaController
 System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Yoga.Models.Role] GetRoles2() on type Yoga.Controllers.YogaController
```

When I disable all but one IQueryable, the results came out fine.

I have googled for similar issues and checked my routing settings, there are no conflicts in controller path and names.

My Routes (default generated):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why you return IQueryable as the return type of your action method ?

Comment: It's a tutorial I saw using MVC4: http://goo.gl/mqzDD
Where the frontend uses upshot.js and it handles IQueryable directly. 
I am not too sure of the exact mechanism

Comment: Returning IQueryable allows you to use OData filters and options in the querystring of that action

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about it !

Comment: @Shyju I'm with you on this one, that looks fugly :)

Comment: @mattytommo I'm new to MVC, what would be the cleaner alternative here?

Comment: If you're new, I'd say stick to the traditional way on returning an `ActionResult` with a model with the data in that you need, that way you don't have to fudge around with routes etc to get this custom behaviour :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC4 is probably matching your HTTP Verb (Get) against all methods with names starting with 'Get' and no parameters. Try forcing the action name:

```
[ActionName("GetRequiredLabels")]
public IQueryable<Yoga.Models.Label> GetRequiredLabels()
...
[ActionName("GetActions")]
public IQueryable<Yoga.Models.Action> GetActions(int BugId)
... // etc
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the routes you pasted and your controller, I think your routes should be:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

i.e. it should have the `{action}` in there. The default MVC4 route would work if you only had a single 'Get' method. Since you have multiple, you'll have to force it to pick the action based on the route.

Comment: Just tried it, I get the same error. I tried including the parameters,  `localhost/api/Yoga/GetActions?BugId=1`, and it simply couldn't find the action: `No action was found on the controller 'Yoga' that matches the request.`

Comment: It's definitely not because you have multiple actions returning IQueryable as I have controllers that do the same. Could you post your route?

Comment: Bravo! Thank you sir, it worked like a charm :) Kind of surprises me that MVC4 didn't include route for multiple actions in a controller by default.

Comment: Great to hear! The MVC4 default route just handles basic CRUD actions for your controller. Assuming you had a `ProductContoller`, you could just hit `localhost/api/product` with any of the four HTTP Verbs and those would route to the methods that match those verbs. You are right though, by default it doesn't allow for more subtle routes