# Why not use content negotiation to return JSON object?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm using `content negotiation` to return a JSON object from some WebAPI controllers.

I found this question 
[How to return Json object on Web API Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231877/how-to-return-json-object-on-web-api-controller)

Here some of the people answered seem to agree that you shouldn't rely on negotiation but should create a new `HttpContent` class for the JSON return.

Why is this please? As a beginner content negotiation seems to work well.

I have searched for this answer, but can't find an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net Web API in its *purest* form is intented to create REST ful web services.

As per REST full standards client should have the ability to decide whether the response should be in XML/JSON response. And this can be achieved using Content-negotiation header in the request.

That means your understanding is correct and using Content negotiation you can decide whether you require XML/JSON response in ASP.Net Web API.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to give you example of this then please create web api by default template. This contain value controller.

Now go to chrome browser and request the data and go to IE and request the data. In chrome you will get XML data while in IE you will get JSON data. ( It ask for download json).

Now if you use tool like fiddler and look at request then you will find difference in request header of both browser.

So if you are sure that you always need json data then it is good to return JSON data from controller action it self. If you don't want to do that and still want all your request to be return JSON then please set header "Accept" with application/json.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

In short if you want to your api always communicated by json data then it is good to return result of json type rather then depend on content negotiation.